# Making CommuniGate Pro react better on SPAM and Backscatter issues

Tags: linux, email, email-bounces, email-server, spam

I would like to make a CGP mail server as SPAM free as possible.

I made some research but didn't find so much.

So my question: where should I start in order to make CommuniGate dealing better with SPAM, backscatter, etc..

Server OS: Linux

CGP Version: 5.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option for [additional spam plugins](http://www.communigate.com/CGPPlugins/) from within Communigate Pro. SpamAssassin is the norm. However, to reduce the load on the mail server, I tend to use external appliances for filtering mail before it reaches the mail system. This is counter to the inline filtering that CGP provides. My preference is the Barracuda Spam Firewall, but there are a number of appliances that can do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I 'll try this what about backscatter issues?

Comment: It seems that you need a license for both MailShell SpamCatcher and Cloudmark Plugin for CommuniGate Pro.
Without the license you can rate up to 5 messages per hour.
There are no alternatives for opensource or community based plugins for Communigate Pro?

Comment: I'd recommend an external unit to keep flexibility (e.g. if you choose to leave CGP at some point).

Comment: I totally agree with you, but it's not an easy migration and it's outside of my scope at the moment.